# Node.js html to pdf with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, express, pdf-generation

I have one html page which is created using the javascript.
For example html page has elements which are appended to html using javascript/jquery functions on document ready.
I want to use node.js express ejs template and html pdf module to create pdf of such html. I can do the pdf generation of static html but not finding anything with dynamic javascript elements.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom-html-to-pdf

Comment: how can i pass the dyanamic ejs template with jquery/javascript code to it?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf check this one js suport

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit

Comment: I checked these but not getting it working

Comment: I am looking something in which i create a ejs template with javascript/jquery which add the elements in the page. Now use that new updated ejs content to create pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129871/discussion-between-adil-and-rahul-tailwal).